# REST Api call fails as Missing the argument though the argument is passed

Tags: rest, curl, centos

I am trying to access an storage array and get certificate token using REST api, but it fails . (I am using Centos 7.5)

```
curl -d '{"username":"admin", "password":"admin"}' -H "Content-Type:
application/json" -X POST "https://Mymachine:5392/v1/tokens" -k
```

It is failing as below.

> {"messages":[{"code":"SM_http_bad_request","severity":"error","text":"The
>   request could not be understood by the
>   server."},{"code":"SM_missing_arg","severity":"error","arguments":{"arg":"username"},"text":"Missing
>   the argument 'username' in the request."}]}

Though i am passing username as argument still it says username is missing. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics of your API, it's hard to tell at casual glance. Have you tried running this using the -v flag to run this in verbose mode and get more information ?

Try running with curl -v (verbose mode) to see if you can get more details.